# What is a reference in C?

Tags: c++, reference, c++-faq

I have just started C++ and have come across references and have not understood completely.

References , as i read  is an alternative name for an object.Why use that instead of directly accessing the object as any operation on references is directly reflected on the object ...?

1. Why and when are they used ?
2. Is ist like a constant pointer that is referenced each time it is used ... ?

And , it says

```
 double& dr = 1;  ----  says it is an error (some lavalue needed) 
 const double& cdr = 1;  ---- says it is ok.
```

i dont understand it properly..So please explain why it is so ...

Thank You...:)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between pointer variable and reference variable in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/difference-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c)

Comment: If you want to know why those two lines work/don't work, look at my answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Why use that instead of directly
>   accessing the object as any operation
>   on references is directly reflected on
>   the object ...?

C++ passes parameters by value, meaning if you have a function such as:

```
void foo(MyObject o) { ... }
```

By default C++ will make a copy of a `MyObject`, *not* directly use the object being passed in.  So, one use of references is to ensure you are working on the same object:

```
void foo(MyObject &o) { ...}
```

Or, if you aren't modifying `o`:

```
void foo(const MyObject &o) { ... }
```

Answer (score 3):

A reference is basically a pointer that looks like an object. It is very very hard to get a NULL reference though you can go through hoops and create one.

With regards to your example, 1 is an rvalue or a result. It is just a temporary variable and can not be modified. Thus you can't take a non const reference to it. However you can take a const reference to it. This means you can't change the value of the reference.

Here is an example of creating a NULL reference. Don't do it!

```
int * x = (int *)NULL;
int & y = *x;
```

Comment: It is impossible to get a "null reference" without invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: Not impossible and you will get a seg-v if you access it probably.

Comment: Impossible *without invoking undefined behavior*. In your example `*x` is a NULL dereference, which is UB.

Comment: Yup, and there are compilers that optimize precisely because you can't have NULL references. So they might not even bother executing your second statement.

Comment: I think my point was that it is possible and it is something coders should watch out for. You may see a seg-v at a place you don't expect it and not at the point you create the reference. Yes this is undefined behaviour but I've seen plenty of code turning member pointers to const references through accessor methods and it's worth knowing what you may have when your code goes bork.

Answer (score 3):

References are another way of what was originally in C code like this

```
void fubarSquare(int *x){
  int y = *x;
  *x = y * y;
}

// typical invocation
int z = 2;
fubarSquare(&z);
// now z is 4
```

with references in C++ it would be like this

```
void fubarSquareCpp(int& x){
   x = x * x;
}

// typical invocation
int z = 2;
fubarSquareCpp(z);
// now z is 4
```

It's a neater syntactical way of using a *call-by-reference* parameter instead of using the C's notation asterisk/star to indicate a pointer and as a *call-by-reference* parameter...and **modifying** the parameter directly outside of the function...

Have a look at Bjarne Stoustrap's page [here](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq.html) which covers how C++ is and also here on the technical faq [here](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you. using references as just an alias name is not very useful.
It is more useful if you consider it as an immutable pointer. But not that useful in fact.

Practically, it is used to define clean interfaces. For example when you define:

```
int foo(const int& param);
```

You say that param is a read-only parameter in foo.

Do not forget that you MUST assign a value to a reference.

See the [C++ faqlite](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/references.html) on references for more

my2c

Comment: I agree. At the level of object interface, it creates a clear contract with the user of the function.
void foo(Object& o){};
The foo function asks for a pointer to an object that can be modified and that is NOT NULL.

Answer (score 1):

Give the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(C%2B%2B)) article a good read through.  To sum it up, references are more friendly version of pointers which are commonly used to pass objects as references into functions without worrying about a null pointer.

### To explain the example:

---

Think of the number `1` represented as a variable.  When compiled, this number is put into the global section of the memory which can be referenced by the program, but **not** modified.

So it is of type: **const int**

`double &dr = 1` is trying to assign `dr` (a **reference to a double**) to the `const int 1`.  Since `1` is a constant, the compiler will not allow you to make a non-constant reference to it.

In the second line:

`const double &dr = 1` is trying to assign `dr` (a **constant reference to a double**) the `const int 1`.  This works because the **reference is also const** and therefore can point to a `const int`.

**EDIT**
The `const int` is converted to a `const double` before assigned.

Comment: Actually, this is not true. The literal `1` is a rvalue of type `int`, not `const int`. You can see the difference here: http://ideone.com/tzV6p. Although `f()` returns a non-const `A`, it cannot be bound to a reference.

Comment: Yes, in that case the literal `1` is a rvalue.  But when dealing with literals that go in the global memoryspace it works (see http://ideone.com/aZnid)

Comment: No, in all cases the literal `1` is an rvalue of type `int`.  The actual value of 1 need not be stored anywhere in memory, unless you explicitly create an lvalue to store it, which is what you do in your linked program.

Comment: then why is `const int &h = 1;` valid?

Comment: Because you are allowed to bind const references to rvalues.  The compiler will perform whatever magic is necessary to make that work.

Comment: okay, so it made 1 into an rvalue somehow, why can't it do that magic for this: `int &h = 1`

Comment: The term rvalue isn't a property of objects, its a property of expressions.  The expression `1` is an rvalue; the compiler doesn't have to do anything to make it one, it just is.  The rules of the language state that if an expression yields an rvalue, you can only bind the result to a constant reference.  If the language changed, then sure, the compiler could store the number 1 somewhere and generate a non-const reference to that, but then you're talking about a whole different thing.

Comment: In this specific example, your explanation is basically good enough.  It gives the intuitive reasoning behind things.  `1` is clearly a constant value, so it makes sense that `int& i = 1;` shouldn't work.  But in the wider concept of understanding references, its an important distinction.  The reason `int f();  int& i = f();` doesn't work is less obvious.

Comment: @Dennis Zickefoose: BTW, the language actually _has_ changed: `int&& i=1` should work.

Comment: wow, lots of fun.  Thanks for the indepth explination @Dennis and @jpalecek!  SO i get all that you are saying except for why `int &i = f();` doesn't work, isnt the result of `f()` a rvalue?

Comment: Yes.  And you can't bind rvalues to non-constant references.  This is just a rule.

Answer (score 1):

References improve the syntax, so no pointer dereference needed.
Assuming Base is a class that may be derived from:

```
void someFunction(Base b)
{
    b.function();
    // b is a copy of what was passed - probably performance issues
    // possible unintended object slicing - you only get the Base part of it
    // no virtual function call
    // no changes to b visible outside the function
}

void someFunction(Base* b)
{
    b->function();
    // a shortcut for (*b).function();
    // b is the same object that was passed to the function
    // possible virtual call
    // changes visible outside the function
}

void someFunction(Base& b)
{
    b.function();
    // b is the same object that was passed to the function
    // possible virtual call
    // changes visible outside the function
}
```

References are like constant pointers (NOT pointers to constants - i.e. you can change the object, but you can't change to what you're pointing). const reference is a reference through which you can do things that can be done on const object.

References are also good, because you can't have a null reference

Answer (score 1):

References are language entitities that represent another object they refer to. Nonconst references are lvalues, and must be initialized with an lvalue. They can be useful like this:

```
int& x=condition ? array[1] : array[2];
int& y=condition ? array[0] : array[3];
x+=y;
y=0;
```

When used as a function parameter, they tell the caller he has to pass an lvalue that might be written to by the function:

```
void set1(int& x) { x=1; }

int foo;
set1(foo); // ok, foo is 1
set1(foo+1); // not OK, not lvalue
```

Const references, on the other hand, can be bound to rvalues. In function parameters, they are usually used to avoid excessive copies:

```
void niceness(std::string s); // the string would be copied by its copy-ctor
void niceness(const std::string& s); // the caller's string would be used
```

Note that this may or may not yield faster code.

When const-references are used in normal code, they can bind rvalues, too, and [as a special rule, they extend the lifetime of the object they are bound to](http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/). This is what you saw in your code:

```
const double& d=1; // OK, bind a rvalue to a const-ref
double& d=1; // Bad, need lvalue
```

All references are polymorphic, like pointers:

```
class A { virtual void f(); }
class B : public A { void f(); }

B b;
A& ar=b;
ar.f(); // calls B::f()
```

and all references are aliases like pointers:

```
int f(int& a, const int& b)
{
  a=1;
  return b;
}

int x;
f(x, 42); // ==42, foo=1
x=42;
f(x, x); // ==1 (not 42), foo=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double& dr = 1; // 1.0 would be more clear
```

Is invalid because `1` is viewed to be of type `const double` so if you want a reference to that variable you need to have a reference to a `const double` so

```
const double& dr = 1.0;
```

Is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Utility of references is most visible in the context of passing parameters to functions.

I.e,

int a;

func definition: void foo (int& param) {param = 1;}

func call: foo(a);

The way as 'param' aliases 'a' is clean and its intention is easily understood by a reader of this code as well as compiler that may optimize away when inlining any additional memory allocation needed for the reference.

Answer (score 0):

Passing a reference to a function and then having the function use the reference is almost like passing a pointer to the function and then having the function dereference the pointer.  In many cases, the machine-code implementation will be identical.  There are some differences, though, especially in the case of functions that get expanded inline.  If a variable is passed by reference to an inline function, the compiler will often be able to substitute the variable itself--even if stored in a machine register--when expanding the function.  By contrast, if one takes the address of a variable and passes that as a pointer to a function which then dereferences it, the compiler is less likely to figure out that optimization unless it determines not only that--at least for one particular expansion of the function--the pointer will always point to that variable, but also that the pointer will not be used anywhere else (if the pointer was used elsewhere, the variable could not be kept in a register).