# In C++ can I pass a structure as a pointer without declaring it locally?

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm working with SDL which is a C library that has declarations of functions like this:

```
void SDL_foo(SDL_Rect *rect);
```

I have my own wrappers around some of the functions like this:

```
void foo(SDL_Rect rect) {
  SDL_foo(&rect);
}
```

This is so I can simply call them like this:

```
foo({x, y, w, h});
```

My question is: is it possible to avoid having a wrapper function and do something like this:

```
SDL_foo(&{x, y, w, h});
```

Thanks!

Comment: reference can not bind to temporary variable

Comment: Looks more like C than C++

Comment: @sebadagostino SDL is a C library I am asking if there is a way to accomplish this "syntactic sugar" in C++

Comment: Feel free to answer with "No" and provide a reason

Comment: Short answer:  no.   The initialiser `{x,y,w,h}` creates an object as a temporary, in order to pass it by value to the function.   `&{x,y,w,h}` attempts to obtain a pointer to that temporary, which is not permitted.    It works in your wrapper, because `rect` is a named variable, not a temporary (at least, in the scope of the function).

Comment: @Peter is there a macro of some kind that can automate this easily or am I stuck making wrapper functions?

Comment: There are options.  Writing a wrapper is the advisable option.   Macros are actively discouraged in C++ for good reasons.   Using a macro for this will encounter all sorts of factors that underpin general advice to not use them.

Comment: You can't get the address of an rvalue, because, unlike lvalues, they don't occupy identifiable locations in memory (lvalue stands for locator value). If that lib you're working with had an overhaul to allow rvalue references (a concept introduced by C++11), things would be easier, I suspect.

Comment: You should not pass around `structs` or objects by value. Pass them by `const` reference.

Comment: @EJP that's not good advice. OP's first example of materialising the temporary in the wrapper argument is exactly the sort of situation where it is appropriate

Comment: @EJP: That's true for some structs, but not for others. It's certainly ok to pass, say, a `struct point { double x; double y; }` by value. But - my answer does agree with you in this particular case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you cannot do that because you can't get the address of a temporary.
But you can probably get away with it with a kind of wrapper like this:

```
struct MyRect {
    MyRect(SDL_rect rect): rect{rect} {}
    operator SDL_rect *() { return &rect; }
    SDL_rect rect;
};

SDL_foo(MyRect{{x, y, w, h}});
```

Not tested yet, but it should give you an idea of what I mean.
This way, instead of creating wrappers for all the functions from SDL, you have to create only a tiny wrapper around `SDL_rect`.
Not sure if it works fine for you anyway.

Comment: Not far, but you should just add some more ctors true copy/move constructors (current on take an object by copy) and most of all `MyRect(int x, int y, int w, int h): rect{x, y, w, h} {}`

Comment: And if you do this, you probably want to template it so
`SDL_foo(Local<SDL_rect>({x, y, w, h}))`.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Given that `SDL_rect` is a type from a C library, there's no way its own move operations could possibly have meanings different from the copy operations.  I might even consider removing the existing `MyRect` constructor so that the type becomes an aggregate.

Comment: @aschepler good point of removing the constructor of `MyRect` indeed.

Answer (score 0):

### tl;dr: Just use references.

You can completely avoid your problem, and get the convenient calling convention you like - without instantiating any unnecessary copies of structs - if your wrappers use *references*. If you're new to C++, you can read this StackOverflow question, which introduces them briefly: **[References in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502687/references-in-c)**.

At any rate, if the SDL function you want to wrap has the signature:

```
void SDL_foo(SDL_Rect *rect);
```

then your wrapper would be:

```
inline void my_wrapper_name(SDL_Rect& rect) {
    SDL_foo(&rect);
}
```

and that works *even if `SDL_Rect` has only been forward-declared*!

Now, if you're sure that the `SDL_Rect` will:

1. Never be used except in the call to `SDL_foo()` and
2. Not be modified by `SDL_foo()` despite it not being designated as taking a `const SDL_Rect*`

you can also write:

```
inline void my_wrapper_name(const SDL_Rect& rect) {
    SDL_foo(const_cast<SDL_Rect*>(&rect));
}
```

in which case you would be able, elswhere in your code and with `SDL_Rect` actually defined, to invoke your wrapper on an initializer list for an `SDL_Rect`.

Comment: I think you'd need my_wrapper_name() to take a (const SDL_Rect &) if you want to be able pass a temporary object to it.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: Well, yes, but - I doubt OP actually want to do that. Let me edit accordingly.

Comment: Sure looks like it to me:  "This is so I can simply call them like this: foo({x, y, w, h});"

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: OP just _thinks_ s/he wants to do that, if `foo()` makes an API call which changes an `SDL_Rect`. If you know what I mean.

Comment: I'm not able to change the calling convention of a third party library like SDL. How could I make this more clear in the future I mentioned it in my post and even tagged it.

Comment: @KristopherIves: I didn't suggest you change the calling conventions of third-party libraries. I just expressed doubt that a library like SDL will not have a const` marker on a pointer parameter whose pointed-to data is not altered.